# Twig use variable in twig array path

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Hi i return an array to Twig template and i want to display it. I want place variable inside of array path.

Let's see array:

```
['kitchen' => [
         'temperature' => '34',
         'humidity' => '67']
'Toilet' => [
         'temperature' => '22',
         'humidity' => '87']
]
```

I return a room's name too, and i want to use it inside path:

```
<span> Temperature: 
{{actual_results.{{ room.name }}.temperature}} </span>
```

But it's now work. It's any possible to do that?

Thanks for help ;)

Comment: {{actual_results[room.name].temperature}}

Comment: It's work! Thanks you!